# Is the Raspberry Pi 4 vulnerable to the Spectre exploits?

Tags: kernel, security

Now the new Raspberry 4 has moved to ARM A72 cores, it's vulnerable to the [**spectre** issues according to ARM](https://developer.arm.com/support/arm-security-updates/speculative-processor-vulnerability).

```
Processor   Variant 1 Variant 2 Variant 3 Variant 3a Variant 4
Cortex-A72   Yes        Yes**    No**      Yes**    Yes
```

But this gives no output:

```
ls -1A /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/*

'/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/*': No such file or directory
```

I do wonder if hardware or software mitigations are in place?

Comment: Have a look through such as https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=243416&p=1484936

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi 4 is using ARM A72, and those ARM A72 Cores have [Speculative Processor Vulnerabilities](https://developer.arm.com/support/arm-security-updates/speculative-processor-vulnerability).

ARM recommends mitigation mechanisms.

The Raspberry Pi 4 has those [mitigations enabled](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=244166&p=1489935#p1489831) in the Raspbian Kernel.

How to check:

```
sudo modprobe configs
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep SPECTRE

CONFIG_CPU_SPECTRE=y
```

Therefor it is safe to say that an **updated** Raspberry Pi 4 is not vulnerable for (any known) Spectre Exploits.

But it is still vulnerable for Spectre issues. Mitigations are mitigations, not fixes.

Comment: this is incorrect. a fully updated Raspberry Pi 4 is still vulnerable to Variant 3a (rogue system register read) and Variant 4 (speculative store bypass). it is unlikely that the system registers that can be read with Variant 3a would contain any sensitive information, but Variant 4 is a much more serious issue. firmware updates are necessary to mitigate both variants (3a and 4), and those aren't available for the Raspberry Pi 4 yet.

Comment: Are there any known exploits?

Comment: https://github.com/google/safeside/blob/main/demos/spectre_v4.cc